# Resolution of plane curve singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves, singularity

Given a plane curve $C$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 and $p\in C$ a singular point, if $f:\tilde{C}\to C$ is a resolution of the singularity and $f^{-1}(p)$ consists of one point, is it true that locally the singularity is of the form $x^m=y^n$ with $m$ and $n$ coprime? Can anything be said if $f^{-1}(p)$ consists of two points?

I've been searching through the vast literature of singularities of plane curves but have been unable to find any good answer.

Comment: From the perspective of blow-ups, the exceptional divisor should be a single point if the tangent cone defines an embedded point, correct? If true, I think this would answer your question in the positive.

Comment: It will depend on what you mean locally-Zariski local or otherwise. For example consider the plane curve $x^3=y^4+y^5$.

Comment: For me in the completed local ring is fine. Or analytically speaking if we're over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any curve, not just planar and not just in characteristic 0, the resolution is just the normalization. Looking at the completed local ring $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,p}$, the normalization is isomorphic to $$\prod_{i= 1}^s k[[x_i]]$$ by the Cohen structure theorem for some $s$. Then the number of points in $f^{-1}(p)$ is exactly the $s$ in this decomposition. In particular, one can produce examples where $f^{-1}(p)$ is a single point by looking at finite index subrings of $k[[x]]$. These are planar if and only if they are generated as a $k$-algebra by $2$ elements.

For an example that is not locally isomorphic to $y^m = x^n$, not even at the level of the completed local ring, consider the subring $k[[t^4, t^6 + t^7]] \subset k[[t]]$ which is the completed local ring of the curve $y^4 = x^7 - x^6 + 4x^5y + 2x^3y^2$.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you.